# I can't find JAVAC.exe

Tags: java, installation

I added *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin* to the system "*Path*" environment variable, but I check inside and there's no **javac.exe** file just **java.exe**

I even made a search by using Windows search.

Do I forget to install something or **javac.exe** file is in another folder?

Comment: You need to install the JDK and add this path to your PATH variable.

Comment: Did you mean Neat Beans? What is the purpose of this java? I mean what is the difference of SDK vs the JAVA that I have installed?

Comment: What you have **runs** java applications.  The SDK is what **compiles** the java code into java applications.  Net Beans is an IDE, not the SDK.

Comment: Ah!, Ok I got it now. I'm trying to start to develop with Android Studio 2.0

Answer (score 5):

the [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) (Java runtime enviroment) and [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (Java development kit) are different things. You need the JDK to compile, because only it has all the tools necessary for compilation, such as `javac`

Comment: So, javac is java compile program?

Comment: Yeah, that is what the C stands for